# Higher-order function in Python

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

When doing the [Homework 3](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61a/sp23/hw/hw03/) of [CS 61A](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61a/sp23/), I meet a problem as shown below in annotation: the name `h` is fine, but initially I use the name `func`, which appears in function `composer` before, and it causes a `RecursionError`. Why?

```
def composer(func=lambda x: x):
    """
    Returns two functions -
    one holding the composed function so far, and another
    that can create further composed problems.
    >>> add_one = lambda x: x + 1
    >>> mul_two = lambda x: x * 2
    >>> f, func_adder = composer()
    >>> f1, func_adder = func_adder(add_one)
    >>> f1(3)
    4
    >>> f2, func_adder = func_adder(mul_two)
    >>> f2(3) # should be 1 + (2*3) = 7
    7
    >>> f3, func_adder = func_adder(add_one)
    >>> f3(3) # should be 1 + (2 * (3 + 1)) = 9
    9
    """
    def func_adder(g):
        "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
        h = lambda x: func(g(x)) # Mind the order
        return composer(h)
        # func = lambda x: func(g(x))
        # return composer(func)
        # Get the Recursion error?
    return func, func_adder
```

I tried the [Python Tutor](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/10/22/pydev-of-the-week-philip-guo/) to visualize the code execution, but I still have difficulty understanding the reason of this error...

Comment: Where did the error happen? Can you show the problematic code (perhaps stripped of comments for brevity), including the call that actually gets you the error?

Comment: If you were to call `func` inside itself (`func = lambda x: func(g(x))`), how would it stop?

Comment: Is CS 61A the [UC Berkeley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_California%2C_Berkeley) one? Is Python Tutor the one [by Philip Guo](https://pg.ucsd.edu/publications/Python-Tutor-scalable-sustainable-research-software_UIST-2021.pdf)?

Answer (score -1):

You call func_adder with a new function g to create h.
You use composer(h) to create a new composer function that includes the composition of func and h.
But, this new composer function is never used to actually perform any computation. Instead, it becomes part of the nested structure of the composer function itself.
Due to this recursion, your code enters an infinite loop, repeatedly creating new composer functions without ever applying the composed functions to any input.
Below code should help solve your issue.

```
def composer(func=lambda x: x):
"""
Returns two functions -
one holding the composed function so far, and another
that can create further composed problems.
"""
def func_adder(g):
    def h(x):
        return func(g(x))  # Compose the functions in the correct order
    return composer(h)

return func, func_adder
```

Comment: What is that? It is not even syntactically correct. What should it be?